# How to add a parameterized DbContext to a Unit of work

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to refactor my asp.net mvc + entity framework project to use repository pattern, and a unit of work. In the newest versions of asp.net mvc DbContext is creating automatically using a parameterized constructor, it looks like this:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

}
```

How can I create an instance of this DbContext in unitOfWork class, what options should I write it the brackets?
P.S: I can't remove the parameters, cause they are used in program.cs in the next way

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'SchoolContext' not found.")));
```

And I also can't add an emty constuctor, cause it will cause an error due to the above statement. (you can't have both constructors)

Comment: What brackets? What's stopping you from creating an instance right now? Or using DI to get an instance?

Comment: What should I enter as a parameter? I mean if I want to create an instance I am writing contextName context = new contextName(what should I write here);

Comment: The constructor of your DbContext requires a DbContextOptions<SchoolContext>. So provide one of those.

Comment: Why you need to create an instance instead of injecting?

Comment: Cause I am trying to add a unit of work class according to microsoft tutorial, and its a bit outdated.

Comment: As `mason` said, You need provide `DbContextOptions<SchoolContext>` as parameter when you create an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I figured it out, here what I was looking for:
In the class create an instance of context

```
private SchoolContext _context;
```

And then initialize it using a constructor like this

```
public UnitOfWork()
    {
        var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SchoolContext>()
            .UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Mentoring.Data;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true")
            .Options;
        _context = new SchoolContext(contextOptions);
    }
```

Comment: Worked for me! Couldn't figure out how to configure UnitOfWork without this. Thanks!